# How to reformat two methods without main into two methods with main

Tags: java

I would really appreciate some tips on how to more effectively format my code, most importantly how to reformat this Celsius to Fahrenheit and Fahrenheit to Celsius program so it has a main method. Additionally, I am getting the error "c declared in methodOne". Can I attach a value to the variable if I declare it in methodOne instead?

```
public class cf {
public static void methodOne (double c, double f) {

    double c = 40;
    double f;
    System.out.println("Celsius Fahrenheit");
     while (c >= 30) {
            f = c * 9/5 +32;
            System.out.println((c) + "   "+Math.round(f*100.0)/100.0);
            c--;
        }
    }

    public static void methodTwo (double e, double a) {
        double e;
        double a = 120;
        System.out.println("Fahrenheit Celsius");
        while (a >= 30) {
            e = a * 5/9 -32;
            System.out.println((a) + "   "+Math.round(e*100.0)/100.0);
            a--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `methodOne` missing the parameter spec (the part after the method name)

Comment: You need a new line between your code and the previous text

Comment: I guess you are getting the error "c declared in methodOne" because you have declared variable ''c" in both 'methodOne" parameters and body,Try changing parameter names.Or just use the "c" and "f' parameter varibales instead declaring them again.

Answer (score 1):

As to your error "c is defined in another class". You take c as a parameter in the method "method one". Why are you taking c in but then immediately defining it to 40? this line makes no sense to me. Either don't take a input or remove the line:

```
 double c = 40;
```

As to adding a main method.

```
public static void main(String [ ] args){
    cf main = new cf();
    main.methodOne(40, 0);
    main.methodTwo(0, 120);
}
```

this can be added as a main method if your remove defining c and a in your two methods and just take the values in as parameters.